# Cannot upgrade Manjaro while in chroot

Tags: ubuntu, grub, chroot, gpg, manjaro

I'm dual booting Manjaro with Ubuntu, for some reason I went back to my Ubuntu and upgraded it a little just to see what's new.

Ubuntu upgrade broke my `grub` config and replaced the Manjaro default (with os-prober).

By broken I mean Kernel Panic on boot for Manjaro, Ubuntu is fine though.

At this point I tried loading my `configfile` from the Manjaro boot partition, it worked but there was some driver error, same happened with all installed Kernels.

In order to bring the system back to live and restoring Manjaro's `grub` while replacing Ubuntu's `grub` I tried `chroot` in to the Manjaro system fro Ubuntu using the official guide by Manjaro for manual chrooting.

The `chroot` succeeded but I'm getting all sorts of messages from `pacman` when I'm trying to update packages.

The messages are:
`error: GPGME error: Invalid crypto engine`

and for each package:

`File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/ncurses-6.0+20161112-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]`

I'll probably try rebooting to Manjaro with the configfile again but I'm skeptical about the results.

My Manjaro version is 16.10 while my Ubuntu version is 16.04.1.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Well the plot thickened as I tried to run `pacman-key --init` and got an error about a missing `libreadline.so.6`, so I tried installing `libreadline` using and Arch xz package and I got a messages saying that I already have that installed, so I looked for the file `libreadline.so.7` and viola! Apparently I had a newer version so I did `ln -s` between the old and new version and the `pacman-key --init` command worked.

At that point all I had to do was to repopulate the key signatures using the command `pacman-key --populate archlinux manjaro`, I thought that was the end of it but apparently I also had to use a script called `pacli-simple` available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/excalibur1234/pacli-simple/master/pacli).

Now I just selected option number 14 after running it and my system was fully upgraded.

After all this process I've discovered some issues with the Nvidia installation but I'll save it for another thread.